# str.replace string by number (python)

Tags: python, replace

I create JSON, I need to replace some string by number. Here is my code:

```
row[1] = row[1].replace('Neuf', '1')
```

The problem is that I end up with "1" when I would like to have the number 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.replace` will always result in a `str`. If you want an int, do the following:

```
row[1] = 1 if row[1] == 'Neuf' else row[1]
```